# Vulkan instance layers return VK_ERROR_LAYER_NOT_PRESENT despite appearing when enumerating layer properties?

Tags: go, layer, vulkan

I'm working with vulkan using vulkan-go bindings. I successfully enumerate through validation layers and confirm that VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation is in that list. I then pass that as a validation layer (and the only validation layer) to my create instance call. It returns a VK_ERROR_LAYER_NOT_PRESENT.

I've verified my registry is correct and all the layers have correct entries.
I've verified the files in the entries exist
I'm using the latest SDK from LunarG at the time of writing (1.1.114.0)
I'm using go bindings from vulkan-go but that appears to not be the issue as it's the call into C that returns the error, and the error is a vulkan response code.
Also happens for any other layer returned in the enumerated layer properties
Extensions work fine, using the same enumeration tactic etc

Enumeration (outputs 12 layers including the one mentioned in the question):

```golang
// FindAvailableInstanceValidationLayers returns a list of available validation layers on your device
func (vkctx *VulkanContext) FindAvailableInstanceValidationLayers() ([]string, error) {
    var count uint32
    if res := vk.EnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&count, nil); res != vk.Success {
        dbg.Error("Failed to get instance validation layer count!")
        return nil, errors.New("failed to get instance validation layer count")
    }

    properties := make([]vk.LayerProperties, count, count)
    if res := vk.EnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&count, properties); res != vk.Success {
        dbg.Error("Failed to enumerate instance validation layers!")
        return nil, errors.New("failed to get instance validation layer count")
    }

    var layers []string

    for _, prop := range properties {
        prop.Deref()
        name := string(bytes.Trim(prop.LayerName[:], "\x00"))
        layers = append(layers, name)
    }

    return layers, nil
}
// returns => [VK_LAYER_NV_optimus VK_LAYER_VALVE_steam_overlay VK_LAYER_VALVE_steam_fossilize VK_LAYER_LUNARG_api_dump VK_LAYER_LUNARG_assistant_layer VK_LAYER_LUNARG_core_validation VK_LAYER_LUNARG_device_simulation VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation VK_LAYER_LUNARG_monitor VK_LAYER_LUNARG_object_tracker VK_LAYER_LUNARG_screenshot VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation VK_LAYER_LUNARG_parameter_validation VK_LAYER_GOOGLE_threading VK_LAYER_GOOGLE_unique_objects VK_LAYER_LUNARG_vktrace]
```

create instance call:

```
// declare app info
    appinfo := &vk.ApplicationInfo{
        SType:              vk.StructureTypeApplicationInfo,
        PApplicationName:   "Stack Overflow Example",
        ApplicationVersion: vk.MakeVersion(1, 0, 0),
        PEngineName:        "no engine",
        EngineVersion:      vk.MakeVersion(1, 0, 0),
        ApiVersion:         vk.ApiVersion11,
    }

    // declare create info (supported layers contains correct string)
    createinfo := &vk.InstanceCreateInfo{
        SType:                   vk.StructureTypeInstanceCreateInfo,
        PApplicationInfo:        appinfo,
        EnabledExtensionCount:   uint32(2),
        PpEnabledExtensionNames: []string{ "VK_KHR_surface", "VK_KHR_win32_surface" },
        EnabledLayerCount:       uint32(1),
        PpEnabledLayerNames:     []string{ "VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation" },
    }


    // create the instance
    inst := new(vk.Instance)
    if result := vk.CreateInstance(createinfo, nil, inst); result != vk.Success {
        // result => vk.ErrorLayerNotPresent
        dbg.Error("Failed to create vulkan instance!")
        return nil, errors.New("vulkan instance creation failed")
    }
```

I expect CreateInstance to pass (or fail for other reasons) but instead it enters the if statement and the "result" variable is set to VK_ERROR_LAYER_NOT_PRESENT. It is using the same string from that list of available layers, so there's no doubt it's the same. It's the only layer. If I use any other layer (say VK_LAYER_LUNARG_core_validation) then it will have the same result. No matter the layer listed in the enumeration.

Comment: "*It's hard to give much more code as it's all tightly integrated and I can't post an entire engine*" Surely, you can just create a new project and write the skeleton code you need to initialize Vulkan. That's what a [mcve] is supposed to be about.

Comment: Please provide an MVCE, doing so helps us and you. You might even figure out what is wrong on your own via doing so.

Comment: I removed the engine code from the example to make it more clear. The second code block is where the error occurs. The only engine code stuff was engine names and getting the list of desired layers. After running this new code I have the same issue. Hopefully this is more clear.

Comment: @gjh33 I'm not familiar with go, but won't you need to store the array some where else so that the reference still exists after the creation of the createinfo? Looks like you are trying to use a reference to a temporary rhs value.

Comment: @opa I don't know it either, but Go is garbage collected language, so it shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: This is using a wrapper with c-go and ensuring the values aren't collected or re allocated.

Comment: Can you try creating a temporary variable for both the extension and layer string arrays and passing that into the struct instead?

Comment: Tried it, and it made no difference. I'm sure it's not a memory issue as I stepped through the library i was using all the way until the call into c code and everything was in order. The call into c code is a streight call into vulkan API. My feeling is it's something to do with the install, but i verified my registry and extensions etc.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem myself today, and since this was a top result for this problem in Google with no answer provided, I will share what I found.

Vulkan expects the strings provided to it in both ppEnabledLayerNames and ppEnabledExtensionNames (as well as in general) to be null-terminated, which currently must be done manually when using vulkan-go.

In your code sample, you've hidden the problem from yourself by trimming all of the NULL bytes from the strings provided by Vulkan with

```
    name := string(bytes.Trim(prop.LayerName[:], "\x00"))
```

It's worth mentioning that vulkan-go provides a function for doing the above conversion, [ToString()](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/vulkan-go/vulkan@v0.0.0-20210402152248-956e3850d8f9#ToString), but it has the same problem. If you want to test strings before using them with CreateInstance or similar, you have to preserve at least one NULL byte:

```
terminus := bytes.IndexByte(prop.LayerName[:], 0)  // Find null terminator
name := string(prop.LayerName[:terminus+1]) // Include single NULL byte
```

Or simply compare the strings without the null terminator then remember to add it after the comparison.          .

Answer (score 0):

I just got hit by this bizarre bug on Linux (my App is in C++) with layers `1.3.261.1`.

The problem is that dlopen failed to load `libVkLayer_khronos_validation.so` because `pthread_create` was not defined.

The solution was simply to do:

```cpp
// Validation layer needs this.
void *libHandle = dlopen( "libpthread.so.0", RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_LAZY );
if(!libHandle)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "dlopen failed: %s\n", dlerror());
}
```

And that fixed it.